# Packaging a native Custom Action DLL and its dependencies

Tags: wix3

Working on a legacy application which use Wix3 to generate an installer, I want to implement a custom action in C++ that will do some calls to libcurl. The issue is that libcurl have some dependencies that I don't know how to embed.

I am aware of MakeSfxCA.exe that can package a custom action written in C# and native dlls, but is there a more native way ?

Answer (score 0):

No one has contributed such a feature to the WiX Toolset yet.